# persistent data using map volume to kong container

Tags: docker

I am trying to learn kong, using docker-compose, i am able to run kong+konga and create services. But whenever i do docker-compose down and then up again i lose all my data:

```
kong:
container_name: kong
image: kong:2.1.4-alpine
restart: unless-stopped
networks:
  kong-net:
    ipv4_address: 172.1.1.40
volumes:
  - kong_data:/usr/local/kong/declarative
environment:
  KONG_DATABASE: postgres
  KONG_PG_HOST: kong-database
  KONG_PG_USER: kong
  KONG_PG_PASSWORD: password
  KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN: "0.0.0.0:8001, 0.0.0.0:8444 ssl"
  KONG_DB_UPDATE_FREQUENCY: 1m
  KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG: /dev/stdout
  KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG: /dev/stdout
  KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG: /dev/stderr
  KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG: /dev/stderr
depends_on:
  - kong-migration
ports:
  - "8001:8001"
  - "8444:8444"
  - "8000:8000"
  - "8443:8443"
```

Looks like volume mapping not working. pleasE help

Comment: the volumn is defined but seems not used.

Comment: sorry, actually i need to map volume in postgres container, not in kong container

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep data when your kong docker-compose is down it is better to use kong in database mode.

So then you will create a persistent volume for your database and it will keep your changes.

By the kong [manual](https://docs.konghq.com/install/docker/?_ga=2.138573171.1515491840.1626598570-1057515845.1626598570#with-a-database) you will find there are two type of database supported: postgresql and cassandra

Postgresql is my choice for small project as I'm not planning for huge horizontal scale with cassandra database.

As you will find in the manual starting your project with docker and database is very simple.
But remember to add a volume to your database service as in the sample mentioned in manual there is no volume.

For postgresql you can add: `-v /custom/mount:/var/lib/postgresql/data` in docker run command

or

```
volumes:
    postgress-data:
        driver: local

services:
    postgress:
        restart: unless-stopped
        image: postgres:latest
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=your_db_user
            - POSTGRES_DB=kong
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=your_db_password
        volumes:
            - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer : **You should use docker volume for having persistent data**

As [reference](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) says :

> Volumes are the preferred mechanism for persisting data generated by and used by Docker containers

First step is to create a volume that you want your host and docker container communicate using :
`docker volume create new-volume`

Second step is to use that volume in a docker-compose **(in your case)**

A single docker compose service with a volume looks like this:

```
 version: "3.9"
 services:
   frontend:
     image: node:lts
     volumes:
       - myapp:/home/node/app
 volumes:
   myapp:
```

On the first invocation of docker-compose up the volume will be created. The same volume will be reused on following invocations.

A volume may be created directly outside of compose with docker volume create and then referenced inside docker-compose.yml as follows:

```
 version: "3.9"
 services:
   frontend:
     image: node:lts
   volumes:
     - myapp:/home/node/app
 volumes:
 myapp:
 external: true
```